# Setting x-axis scale to only some values in my data python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data, and I would like to draw a scatter plot, and set x-axis scale to only some data, here is the example
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

```
Data2 = {'Result1': [0.9679,0.9620,0.9618,0.9697,0.9721,0.9364],
        'Result2': [0.92,0.9162,0.9236,0.9387,0.9306,0.9066],
        'Result3': [0.914,0.9233,0.9334,0.9361,0.9316,0.8944],
        

        'K': [0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5]
       }
  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Data2,columns=['K','Result1,'Result2','Result3'])
sns.set(style='whitegrid')
sns.scatterplot(x='K', y='Result1', data=df2,label="Result1",marker='o',legend=None)
sns.scatterplot(x='K', y='Result2', data=df2,label="Result2",marker='o',legend=None)
sns.scatterplot(x='K', y='Result3', data=df2,label="Result3",marker='o',legend=None)

plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('performance', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks([0.001,0.01,0.1]
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.7, bottom=0.1)
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.savefig("reults",bbox_inches = "tight")
```

example output

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want this output

[image]

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Did you try `plt.xscale('log')`?

Comment: Thank you @JohanC, imagine it works